# Python while loop not terminating after defined amount of time

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, raspberry-pi, traceback

For this project, I have been making a vibration measurement device that plots high speed vibrations that are controlled by a motor. Here is the code below:

```
# Import the modules
from __future__ import division
import spidev, datetime, time
from sys import exit
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Setup SPI
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.mode = 3

# Constants
accres, accrate = 1, 15

# Set GPIO chip select pins
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
cs1, cs2, motor = 23, 24, 18
GPIO.setup(cs1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(cs2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(motor, GPIO.OUT)

# Note: the duty cycle goes from 0.0 to 100.0, with 100.0 being no motor movement,
# and 0.0 being the maximum motor speed.
motor_output = GPIO.PWM(motor, 60)

# Initialize the ADXL345
def initadxl345():
    # Set data rate (accrate=15 -> 3200 Hz, 14=1600 Hz, 13=800 Hz, 12=400 Hz, 11=200 Hz, 10=100 Hz etc.)
    spi.xfer2([44, accrate])

    # Enable full range (10 bits resolution) and +/- 16g 4 LSB
    spi.xfer2([49, accres])

# Read the first ADXL x-y-z axes
def readadxl345_1():
    # Chip select pin ensures that the first sensor is being read by grounding its pin
    GPIO.output(cs1, 0)
    GPIO.output(cs2 ,1)

    rx = spi.xfer2([242, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    out = [rx[1] | (rx[2] << 8), rx[3] | (rx[4] << 8), rx[5] | (rx[6] << 8)]
    # Format x-axis
    if (out[0] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[0] = out[0] - (1 << 16)
    # Format y-axis
    if (out[1] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[1] = out[1] - (1<<16)
    # Format z-axis
    if (out[2] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[2] = out[2] - (1 << 16)
    # Return human readable values
    return out

# Read the second ADXL x-y-z axes
def readadxl345_2():
    # Chip select pin ensures that the first sensor is being read by grounding its pin
    GPIO.output(cs1, 1)
    GPIO.output(cs2 ,0)

    rx = spi.xfer2([242, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    out = [rx[1] | (rx[2] << 8), rx[3] | (rx[4] << 8), rx[5] | (rx[6] << 8)]
    # Format x-axis
    if (out[0] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[0] = out[0] - (1 << 16)
    # Format y-axis
    if (out[1] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[1] = out[1] - (1<<16)
    # Format z-axis
    if (out[2] & (1 << 16 - 1 )):
        out[2] = out[2] - (1 << 16)
    # Return human readable values
    return out

print("Vibration Reader Initializing...")
time.sleep(1)
print(GPIO.RPI_INFO)
time.sleep(1)

response = input("Proceed measurements? [Y, n] ")

if response == "Y" or "y":
    filename = input("Filename: ")
    pwm_speed = float(input("Motor PWM value: "))
    # Initialize the ADXL345 accelerometer
    print("Initializing ADXL345s...")
    initadxl345()
    motor_output.start(pwm_speed)
    print("Motor is up and running at {}".format(pwm_speed))
    time.sleep(1)

    timeout = 0.0003125 / 2 # timeout=1/samplerate=>not sufficient measurements. Half the time is sufficient (don't know why!)

    timetosend = 1

    while True:
       with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f: # get uptime
           uptime_start = float(f.readline().split()[0])
       uptime_last = uptime_start
       active_file_first = filename + '.csv'
       file = open('/var/log/sensor/' + active_file_first, 'w')
       while uptime_last < uptime_start + timetosend:

           time1 = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%S.%f'))
           sensor1 = readadxl345_1()
           sensor2 = readadxl345_2()
           file.write(str(sensor1[0]) + ',' + str(sensor1[1]) + ',' + str(sensor1[2]) + ',' + str(sensor2[0]) + ',' + str(sensor2[1]) + ',' + str(sensor2[2]) + ',' + time1 + '\n')

           # Print data every "timeout" second
           elapsed = time.process_time()
           current = 0
           while(current < timeout):
               current = time.process_time() - elapsed

    motor_output.stop
    print("Motor shutting off and cleaning up GPIO.")
    GPIO.cleanup()

elif response == "N" or "n":
    print("Quitting...")
    time.sleep(1)
    quit()
```

From this I get into trouble. The issue is that once I do choose to proceed, the print statement `Motor is up and running at 100.0` displays and nothing happens until I press a random key on the keyboard in which is says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "accelerometer.py", line 116, in <module>
    current = time.process_time() - elapsed
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Its as if the code following that print statement didn't even exist, or the interpreter just ignored it completely. Does anyone have a coherent explanation of these problems?

Comment: `if respones == 'Y' or (any other Truthy value)` prevents you from entering `n`. (Seems to be not the problem, though, unless you are using this malconstruct elsewhere.)

Comment: I just figured that out. However, the motor issue still persists.

Comment: Your `# Print data every "timeout" second` has no code that prints out any data. I suspect your code is running as intended, but there is nothing to break out of the top-nested while loop, and nothing sent to the console, so it runs infinitely and silently until you tell the program to stop, hence the KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: I would add `print` or `log` statements to trace what is happening and clearly see what code is executed and what not. Also, do you see anything added to your `/var/log/sensor/<filename>` file?

Comment: @sal It turns out that it is creating the files, but it doesn't stop printing even after one second or so

Comment: @PeptideWitch do you have any recommendations? I take it that the print statement means that it is printing to the CSV file, but if not, is there a way that I can terminate it after about one second?

Comment: That's right - it's taking the sensor1/2 info and writing it to the csv file. In order to figure out how to terminate after a desired time, we need to understand a few things. `uptime_last = uptime_start` - does uptime_last need to be checked over and over, or is it a fixed measure that you can read once?

Comment: @PeptideWitch I don't know if it needs to. I think the code does this to know what the elapsed time is because in the RPi it is constantly updated with some sort of time stamp... I don't know if I need it or not

Comment: @usr2564301 I was also wondering if there is a way to combine the read functions into a single line with the csv write command in the loop. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a step back and think about what this block of code is doing:

```
while True:

   ### Block 1 ###
   with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f: # get uptime
       uptime_start = float(f.readline().split()[0])
   uptime_last = uptime_start
   active_file_first = filename + '.csv'
   file = open('/var/log/sensor/' + active_file_first, 'w')

   ### Block 2 ###
   while uptime_last < uptime_start + timetosend:

       time1 = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%S.%f'))
       sensor1 = readadxl345_1()
       sensor2 = readadxl345_2()
       file.write(str(sensor1[0]) + ',' + str(sensor1[1]) + ',' + str(sensor1[2]) + ',' + str(sensor2[0]) + ',' + str(sensor2[1]) + ',' + str(sensor2[2]) + ',' + time1 + '\n')
       # Print data every "timeout" second
       elapsed = time.process_time()
       current = 0

       ### Block 3 ###
       while(current < timeout):

           current = time.process_time() - elapsed
```

Block 1 checks an uptime file, reads the time and then opens a `file`. However, if this `uptime_start` variable never changes, then we can just set it once outside of (and instead of) the top `while` loop. Block 2 then checks `uptime_last < uptime_start + x`, but in the previous few lines, you've defined `uptime_last = uptime_start`. This means that for as long as the timetosend is not negative, this loop will execute infinitely unless an internal break condition is met. Block 2 writes sensor data to file. Block 3 does a time calculation until a condition is met, but doesn't really do anything with this information.

My guess as to what could be a good answer is this:

```
### Block 1 ###
with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f: # get uptime
    uptime_start = float(f.readline().split()[0])
file = open('/var/log/sensor/' + filename + '.csv', 'w')
time_elapsed = 0
time_start = time.process_time()

### Block 2 ###
while time_elapsed < uptime_start:

   time1 = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%S.%f'))
   sensor1 = readadxl345_1()
   sensor2 = readadxl345_2()
   file.write(str(sensor1[0]) + ',' + str(sensor1[1]) + ',' + str(sensor1[2]) + ',' + str(sensor2[0]) + ',' + str(sensor2[1]) + ',' + str(sensor2[2]) + ',' + time1 + '\n')

   time_elapsed = time.process_time() - time_start
```

Comment: when I integrate that code I get this error: `while time_elapsed < uptime_start: NameError: name 'time_elapsed' is not defined`

Comment: Ah my mistake - you'll need to initialise: add `time_elapsed = 0` above the loop

Comment: Sorry to add frustration into the mix but it still doesn't stop after a second. It is only until I stop the script manually that it stops outputting to a file.

Comment: Best thing to do is to print out the value of `uptime_start` before the loop. Then, during the Block 2 while loop, add `print(time_elapsed)` on the last line. That way you can see what's happening. If you want to stop after exactly 1 CPU process second, then change `uptime_start` to 1

Comment: It prints a bunch of random values and it doesn't stop until I end the script. They look like `0.00014963599999973098` and other inconsistent values. Am I also supposed to keep the `while True:` script from your first segment?

Comment: Apologies again - I'm not thinking straight. `time_start = time.process_time()` needs to be outside of the while loop otherwise it will be initialised every time the loop begins. I've edited my answer

Comment: You are totally fine. I tested it out and the counting of the time in the print statement is working. However, it is still not ending after one full second

Comment: `time.time()` may be more appropriate for your code here; with `uptime_start` changed to 1, do you find that the while loop is indeed ending?

Comment: Yes that makes it stop after 1 second when I change `uptime_start` to one. Do you think I should change it to time.time() and if so, where?

Comment: Glad to hear. So `time.time()` will use real world seconds whereas `time.process_time()` excludes time the processor spends sleeping; I'd use `time.time()` in this example

Comment: Ya it seems to do the same thing but just a little better. Thanks for the help. I would want to continue asking questions about the output, but do you want to move this to a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207314/discussion-between-s-r-colledge-and-peptidewitch).

Comment: Happy to - but best practice would be to start another question with a more defined problem, and that way other people can contribute their ideas too. It also prevents our interaction from becoming an endless chain of new problems (chasing rabbits). Oh, and if you're happy with the answer here, you can mark it as 'accepted'.